# Visual Studio Xamarin iOS storyboard scrollview does not scroll

Tags: ios, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, uiscrollview, xamarin.ios

I am using Visual Studio 2015 to write a Xamarin iOS application using the storyboard. My problem is that I cannot get a scrollview to scroll. However table views scroll just fine.

Looks fine in portrait mode but when rotated to landscape the scrolling does not enable

I have tried putting a view inside the scrollview to hold to fields however that made no difference. What am I missing?

Screenshot of storyboard

[image]

Screenshot of document outline
[image]

Screenshot of scroll view constraints (none)

[image]

Comment: Do you have the `UIScrollView` size constrained to the parent view? If you don't pin its size, then the scroll view can "grow" and its content will be off the screen.

Comment: How do I do this, where can I check that setting?

Comment: It isn't really a setting. It's in your constraints. Can you attach a screenshot of the constraints on the scroll view?

Comment: Added screenshot of constraints there are none... Not sure how to add them. Sorry I am new to Xamarin. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Hey no worries. We all start somewhere. Check out this [Xamarin iOS designer overview](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/designer/designer_auto_layout/) I think it's for Xamarin Studio, but everything is the same for Visual Studio. Basically, create constraints from the top, left, right, and bottom of the scroll view to its parent view. That will probably be the Top Layout Guide, leading container margin, trailing container margin, and Bottom Layout Guide respectively.

Comment: Yea this is still no good as Visual Studio only lets you add "recommended constraints" not define your own (if you can I have not been able to find where that would be).

Comment: I think you can add whatever constraints you want. Click on the element until the constraint handles appear  - usually 2 clicks, then drag a handle to another element (such as Top Layout Guide, container leading edge, etc.) and drop it. Unless that's what you mean by "recommended constraints".

Comment: I just got it to work, I had to programmatically set the scrollView ContentSize in the ViewDidLoad to be larger. Thank you for your help.